# Oracle Apex - Convert WKT geometries to Shapefile format

Tags: javascript, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-spatial

I wanted to add to my application using Oracle APEX, the functionality of downloading spatial geometries in files in the "KML, GeoJSON and Shapefile (.shp)" format. With Oracle properties I can convert to "KML and GeoJSON" easily using `SDO_UTIL.`:

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_KMLGEOMETRY(SDO_GEOMETRY(table_column)) AS KML FROM my_table    
SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_GEOJSON(SDO_GEOMETRY(table_column)) AS GEOJSON FROM my_table
```

However, I haven't found a way to convert and generate the files to the "Shapefile" format, is there any way to do this in APEX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conversion function inside the Oracle Database to create Shapefiles, which APEX could use.